# How do I make onclick "window.location" also work when user opens in new window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

To hide the true destination of a link I'm using the following code:

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="window.location='http://url-i-want-to-hit.com/'; return false;">Click me</a>
```

However, if I do right-click and then open in new window, it goes to the URL specified in the anchor href tag. I want it to go to the URL specified in the JavaScript.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: and what's a valid reason for doing this?

Comment: why are you being evil?

Comment: in my defense it's for a client who wants to hide affiliate url

Comment: @Josh do you mean create a page called test.php, for example, that redirects to the url-i-want-to-hide.com and then link to test.php?

Comment: Actually, see my answer.  I got it working great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is a mousedown handler to fake them out...

```
<a href="http://example.com"
   onmousedown="this.href2 = this.href;
                this.href = 'http://url-i-want-to-hide.com/';"
   onmouseout="if(this.href2) this.href = this.href2;">Test</a>
```

And here is a [live demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/dNwQQ/3/) of it working.

Comment: i would also add `onblur` event to restore original url, because otherwise after click url will no longer be hidden

Comment: how would I create onblur event? (I'm a javascript novice)

Comment: @Steven @vittore Actually `onblur` is not a valid event for the anchor element.  We are looking for `onmouseout`.  Answer updated again, and  I updated the live demo as well.

Comment: @josh I tried that but when I do a right click it shows the url I want hidden

Comment: @Steve Dude, this is as good as it gets!  They're going to see the address when the page comes up anyways.

Comment: @Steve Plus, this answers the question you asked.  When they choose open in new window, it does what you want it to do.  If I were you I would stop trying to hide the URL because it simply can't be done to the extent you want to do it.

Comment: I added onfocus event and it hides the address in ie but not in firefox. If anyone can suggest something for firefox that would be great

Answer (score 2):

> However, if I do right-click and then open in new window, it goes to the url specified in the anchor href tag. I want it to go to the url specified in the javascript.

No, but you could use JS to set the link href to the hidden URL after the document has loaded (or in the `onfocus` and `onhover` events of the link, although that feels rather kludgy and incomplete).

```
<a onfocus="this.href='hidden_url'" .....>
```

this is the way Google use to count outgoing links from the search results page.

Comment: could you post the entire code for your examples, as I don't quite follow. Thanks

Comment: @Steven what is unclear? This is off the top of my head, so I don't have full examples ready

Comment: your example uses onfocus to show the hidden url, which is the opposite of what I want. Anyhow it doesn't work in firefox. But what you said first is interesting. How would I do that? Thanks

Comment: @Steven nope, what I said first won't in fact work, you will see the hidden URL when hovering. The focus/click solution will work somehow (as I said, Google do this to hide their counter) but probably comes with some quirks I don't know more about

Comment: also add onblur handler to restore url

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  Right click uses the true anchor, whereas you are overriding the click functionality of the anchor with javascript.  A bit deceptive aren't we?

Comment: Google do the same thing to count outgoing hits

Comment: Yes it is deceptive, and that is clearly the point.  Google *does* do this on their search results.  Go ahead, do a search and hover over a result.  See the URL in the status bar?  Now right click the link, copy shortcut, and paste it in address bar.  Whoa!

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the real urls in a database and calling them in php?

```
www.yourwebsite.com/url.php?id=3
```

url.php // something like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `id` = " . intval($_GET['id']);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

header ("location: $row['url']");
```

Comment: Just a small note that this is extremely dangerous piece of code - at least escape the $_GET['id'] before including it in the query using (for example) mysql_real_escape_string - otherwise it's wide open to sql injection

Comment: @Seb There, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't clear...sorry. Using an "#" would prevent them opening a different page in a new window. This may not work for your situation, and I don't know if you are trying to get something accomplished with SEO by hidding the URL. My solution is virtually the same as what you are currently doing except for the "#" in the href and I just prefer to have the window.location wrapped in a function....personal preference.

```
<a href="#" onclick="SendToUrl(); return false;"">Click Here</a>
```

```
<script language="javascript">
   function SendToUrl(){
       window.location='http://url-i-want-to-hide.com/'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Pekka: Updated answer. @Steven: I guess I am not sure why you are trying to do what you are trying accomplish with the way you are linking. Once you send them to the address you are trying to hide won't it just show up in the address bar? The only reason I could think of to do this was to maybe try to manipulate search relevance (SEO).